# Finding a series that fits the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find x for $\sum_{1}^{30} 35*x^{30} = 420 $

I'm trying to find exponential decay so the sum of the intermediate results fits a given sum.
Kind of an extension of standard compound interest.
Sorry if it's too basic.

Comment: You seem to be missing the $i$ index somewhere in the summand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The question, as stated, does not make sense. Namely, $\sum_{x=1}^{30} 35*x^{30}$ is a fixed number (and a rather large one, at that).

Comment: Did maybe you mean $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{30} 35x^j = 420$?  Or maybe $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{30} 35(j*x)^{30} = 420$ or $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{30} 35(\frac xj)^{30} = 420$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is  the correct term, then the answer is trivial, $x = \left[ \frac{420}{35 \times 31}\right]^{\frac{1}{30}}$.

If what you want to find is the solution to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{30} 35  x^i = 420$, we know that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}x^i = \frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}$ for $x\neq 1$. Then, assuming $x\neq 1$, the problem is equivalent to solving:

$$ 35 \frac{x^{31} -1}{x-1} = 420 $$

Or

$$ x^{31} - \frac{420}{35} x  + \frac{420}{35}-1 =0 $$.